# Angular HTTP GET not hitting Express Route

Tags: node.js, angular

My Angular HTTP GET Request indside clearNotifications() in notification.service.ts not hitting Express Route routes/notifications.js. I am calling clearNotifications() from a component called app.component.ts. I am using Angular 7+

**routes/notifications.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();

//Additional modules
// const db = require('../config/database');
// const notificationModel = require('../models/notifications');

//Test connection
// db.authenticate().then(() => {
//     console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
// }).catch(err => {
//     console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
// });

//Clear all notifications
router.get('/clear', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('clear');
    // notificationModel.destroy({});
});
```

module.exports = router;

**notification.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class NotificationService {

  uri = 'http://localhost:5000'; 
  private socket = io(this.uri);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getNotification() {
    let observable = new Observable<{ string: String, number: String }>(observer => {
      this.socket.on('notification', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);
      });
      // return () => { this.socket.disconnect(); }
    })
    return observable;
  }

  clearNotifications() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.uri}/notifications/clear`);
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [NotificationService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'client';

  string: String;
  number: String;
  notificationArray: Array<{ string: String, number: String }> = [];

  constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) {
    this.notificationService.getNotification().subscribe(data => {
      this.notificationArray.push(data);
    });
  }

  clearNotifications() {
    this.notificationArray = [];
    this.notificationService.clearNotifications();
  }
}
```

Comment: @xyz no i am not. but is it important apart from getting a response?

Comment: Yes, a subscription is important to activate the Observable and trigger a request!

Comment: @xyz but i am only concerned about clearNotifications()

Comment: As described in the answers below, this.http.get(`${this.uri}/notifications/clear`) is an observable, but your request won't go unless you add a `subscribe()` to the Observable

Comment: where are you calling `clearNotifications` from?

Comment: @nircraft from a component. i will add it. wait.

Comment: @ShouryaSharma, you should do `this.notificationService.clearNotifications().subscribe( (data) => { ..})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing this: Check the [basic routing on express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/clear', (req, res) => {
    console.log('clear');

 res.send(success);
// notificationModel.destroy({});
});
```

Also make sure to `subscribe` to the service method from your component. If you do not subscribe the `observables` won't execute.

Where are you calling `clearNotifications` from?

subscribe to `clearNotifications` in component and this will work:
 `this.notificationService.clearNotifications().subscribe( (data) => { ..})`

> As a publisher, you create an Observable instance that defines a subscriber function. This is the function that is executed when a consumer calls the `subscribe()` method. The **subscriber** function defines how to obtain or generate values or messages to be published

Answer (score 0):

In `angular`, `http` request returns `observable`, so you need to `subscribe`. If there aren't any subscriber to the `observable`, it wont be executed. Try

```
    clearNotifications() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.uri}/notifications/clear`)
               .subscribe(data => //your callback function,
                          error => // your error handler,
                          complete => // any after completion task);
  }
```